# N 日前の時刻を取得したい

Tags: centos, unix, command-line

サーバー上で、 N 日前の時刻(日付ではなく)をフォーマットしながら文字列として取得したくなりました。 `date` コマンドによってフォーマットをかけるのは知っているのですが、これを任意に printf したりする方法が、パッと思い浮かばないと思っています。

## なので:

上記のやりたいことは、 CentOS 環境ではどのように実現されますか？

## 具体的には:

例えば、以下の様なことがやりたいです。

```
$ some_command some args
```

を例えば今(2019-09-18 15:58:00)実行すると、

```
2019-09-16 15:58:00
```

(この場合は2日まえ)

が取得される様なコマンドです。

Comment: GNU coreutils に含まれる date コマンドであれば `date +'%F %T' --date '-2 day'` など。

Comment: 引数に何を指定したいのかがイマイチ分からないです (片方は日数なんでしょうが)。 / 求める結果は`date`コマンドなら`date --date '2 days ago' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`で出せるはずですが、これじゃ長いから別の方法が無いか？ということでしょうか。 / ぴったり N 日前なら時間(hh:mm:ss)は今現在と一緒ですよね？

Comment: @cubick --date が、自分の欲しかったオプションの様子です。。なので、回答投稿していただけると、 accept ができるかなと思っています。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

最近のLinuxであれば`date`コマンドの`--date`オプションにて未来、または過去の日時を
(文字列で)指定して結果を取得できます。

**manマニュアルのオプションから抜粋**

```
-d, --date=STRING
    「現在」ではなく、STRING で指定された時刻を表示する
```

**例:**

```
> date --date '1 day'        # 1日後
> date --date 'tomorrow'     # 1日後(単語で指定)
> date --date '2 days ago'   # 2日前
```

`2 days ago`じゃなく`2 day ago`でも動きます。また、[@metropolis さんがコメントした](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/59134/n-%e6%97%a5%e5%89%8d%e3%81%ae%e6%99%82%e5%88%bb%e3%82%92%e5%8f%96%e5%be%97%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84?noredirect=1#comment63674_59134)ようにマイナス指定でもいけるようです。表示形式は通常通り、お好みでフォーマットを指定してください。
(頻繁に使うならaliasやバッチファイルを用意してもいいかもしれません)